# R - read in a list of files from a list of zip archives without unzipping them

Tags: r, list, zip, shapefile

I am trying to read in a list of shapefiles from a list of zip archives without actually unzipping the archives. Yes, I know that the archives will be unzipped in the background, but what I want to avoid is seeing the unzipped files in Windows Explorer.

This example can be fully reproducible, you need to download all the files from [this Github repository](https://github.com/generalpiston/geojson-us-city-boundaries/tree/master/shapes) and set your working directory to the folder where you downloaded them.

I also want to do it tidyverse-style, with pipes and without saving intermediate objects.

The code that I am currently trying to run is this one:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(sf)

list.files() %>% 
  map(unzip, list = T) %>% 
  map(filter, grepl(".shp$", Name)) %>% 
  map(~ .x %$% Name) %>% 
  map2(.x = ., .y = list.files(), .f = ~st_read(unzip(zipfile = .y, files = .x)))
```

However, that doesn't work. Why?

**EDIT**: To make the example more minimal, I guess you could also download just two of the files from the above repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`/vsizip`](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsizip-zip-archives) GDAL Virtual File System driver is kind of convenient:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

(file_list <- list.files(pattern = "\\.zip$"))
#> [1] "tl_2019_01_place.zip" "tl_2019_02_place.zip"
sf_list <- file_list %>% 
  # resulting list will have names without ".zip"
  set_names(str_remove(.,"\\.zip$")) %>%  
  map( ~ st_read(paste0("/vsizip/", .x)))
#> Reading layer `tl_2019_01_place' from data source `/vsizip/tl_2019_01_place.zip' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 586 features and 16 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -88.4442 ymin: 30.19825 xmax: -84.96303 ymax: 34.99807
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83

#> Reading layer `tl_2019_02_place' from data source `/vsizip/tl_2019_02_place.zip' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 354 features and 16 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -176.6967 ymin: 51.81049 xmax: 173.4299 ymax: 71.34019
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83

# 1st sf in the list:
sf_list$tl_2019_01_place %>% select(NAME, geometry)
#> Simple feature collection with 586 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -88.4442 ymin: 30.19825 xmax: -84.96303 ymax: 34.99807
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#> First 10 features:
#>           NAME                       geometry
#> 1        Berry MULTIPOLYGON (((-87.6391 33...
#> 2      Fayette MULTIPOLYGON (((-87.85507 3...
#> 3       Gu-Win MULTIPOLYGON (((-87.88578 3...
#> 4     Ashville MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.30442 3...
#> 5     Margaret MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.46153 3...
#> 6    Odenville MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.38406 3...
#> 7  Littleville MULTIPOLYGON (((-87.68859 3...
#> 8      Ragland MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.18473 3...
#> 9   Fort Payne MULTIPOLYGON (((-85.74184 3...
#> 10    Sylvania MULTIPOLYGON (((-85.85684 3...

# 2nd sf in the list:
sf_list$tl_2019_02_place %>% select(NAME, geometry)
#> Simple feature collection with 354 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -176.6967 ymin: 51.81049 xmax: 173.4299 ymax: 71.34019
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#> First 10 features:
#>           NAME                       geometry
#> 1   Whale Pass MULTIPOLYGON (((-133.1884 5...
#> 2    Utqiagvik MULTIPOLYGON (((-156.9255 7...
#> 3    Anchorage MULTIPOLYGON (((-150.4199 6...
#> 4  Toksook Bay MULTIPOLYGON (((-165.2769 6...
#> 5       Angoon MULTIPOLYGON (((-134.6313 5...
#> 6     Kaktovik MULTIPOLYGON (((-143.6574 7...
#> 7   Point Hope MULTIPOLYGON (((-166.8401 6...
#> 8        Homer MULTIPOLYGON (((-151.655 59...
#> 9     Kachemak MULTIPOLYGON (((-151.4731 5...
#> 10       Kenai MULTIPOLYGON (((-151.3526 6...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could define a little function that downloads the zip file, unzips it, reads the shape file into memory, removes the temporary files, then just returns the `sf` object.

The following function does all that:

```r
read_online_zip_sf <- function(url) {
  dir.create("~/zipdir")
  f <- tempfile(tmpdir = "~/zipdir", fileext = ".zip")
  download.file(url, f)
  files <- unzip(f, list = TRUE)
  unzip(f, files = files$Name, exdir = "~/zipdir/files")
  obj <- sf::st_read("~/zipdir/files")
  unlink("~/zipdir", recursive = TRUE)
  return(obj)
}
```

So, now without any mucking about in file explorer, we can do:

```r
url <- paste0("https://github.com/generalpiston/geojson-us-city-boundaries/",
              "raw/master/shapes/tl_2019_02_place.zip")

mysf <- read_online_zip_sf(url)
#> Reading layer `tl_2019_02_place' from data source 
#>   `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\zipdir\files' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 354 features and 16 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -176.6967 ymin: 51.81049 xmax: 173.4299 ymax: 71.34019
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
```

This seems to be a shapefile of city boundaries in Alaska, so let's plot them for completeness:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)

usa <- ne_countries(50, country = "United States of America", 
                    returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(usa) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_sf(data = mysf, fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-180, -131), ylim = c(51, 72)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>